# Zip files to archive from SQL Server Agent job

Tags: t-sql, shell

I've written a program in Access vba that goes to a fixed directory, zips all files in that directory (and subdirectories), and places the zip archive in a (typically) new directory for archival storage. It's the backup routine for my Access Front End and associated files. I've been running it from my client machine every day, using my personal credentials. Now I want to run it from my small SQL Server machine since it is more robust, and accountable. I'd prefer to do it all in T-SQL rather than "calling" the Access routines.

I've done some research, but can't find anything definitive that will help me with this. Can someone point me to some help? Here is the Access VBA code:

```
Function Zip_All_Files_in_Folder()
    Dim FileNameZip, FolderName
    Dim strDate As String, TargetPath As String
    Dim oApp As Object

    TargetPath = "H:\xxx\secure\Construction\Access\All Database Backup\" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MMM") & "_Backup\"
    If Len(Dir(TargetPath)) = 0 Then
        MkDir (TargetPath)
    End If

    FolderName = "H:\xxx\secure\Construction\Access\CPAS\"
    strDate = Format(Date, "YY-MM-DD")
    FileNameZip = TargetPath & strDate & ".zip"

    'Create empty Zip File
    NewZip (FileNameZip)

    'Copy the files to the compressed folder
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items

    'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim time As Integer
    Do Until (oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = _
       oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items.Count) Or time > 180
       Sleep (1000)
       time = time + 1
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Send a message about the way the script ended
    If time < 180 Then
        SendEmail "xxxxxx@yyyyyy.com", "Looks like the zip backup worked." & vbCrLf & TargetPath
    Else
        SendEmail "xxxxxxx@yyyyy.com", "Better double check the Zip backup: " & time & " seconds" & vbCrLf & TargetPath
    End If
    DoCmd.Quit
End Function

Sub NewZip(sPath)
    'Create empty Zip File
    'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File operations or other shell operations from the shell are difficult from TSQL because there is no built-in support for them and permissions are a common problem (the SQL Server service accounts may not have permission to access the filesystem).

The easiest solution is simply to write a standalone script in your preferred language; not an Access-based script, because Microsoft [recommends against](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) server automation using Office. Then schedule it as a SQL Server job or using the Windows scheduler. Unfortunately you haven't mentioned either your version or edition of SQL Server, so it isn't clear what capabilities your server has (e.g. Express Edition does not include SQL Agent, so no scheduled jobs).

Comment: SS2k5 Full, Office2007, MSServer2k8

Comment: OK, then you have the possibility to create a scheduled job in SQL Server to run your script, and you might also want to have a look at maintenance plans too. But the simplest solution is still a standalone script.